# Update multiple Certificate friendly names using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am fairly new to PowerShell and I am currently updating a large list of Certificate Friendly names remotely using PowerShell.

I have done the below script which works fine if there is one certificate but it fails if there is multiple certificates in the store as I need to add a Loop into the script. When I am trying to add a loop in it doesn't seem to be working. Could someone help or point me in the right direction please?

Enter-PSSession –ComputerName Servername

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$CertStore = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\"
$FriendlyName = 'Examplename'
$cert = Get-ChildItem $CertStore
$cert.FriendlyName = $FriendlyName
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `$cert | foreach {$_.FriendlyName = $FriendlyName}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a Foreach Loop into the script.
Something like below:

```
$CertStore = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\"
$FriendlyName = 'Examplename'
$cert = Get-ChildItem $CertStore | foreach {$_.FriendlyName = $FriendlyName}
```

And this will update multiple Certificates with friendly names.

Comment: No prob @MikeR. Accept this as answer, if its helping you. May be this helps others, who view ur post :)